# Ccheck if struct exists

Tags: go

I am looping through a slice of `type company struct` and inside every company there is a `type image struct` so when I loop through the company slice I have an if statement where I want to check if the `company.Image` is nil or not, but I receive the following error `Cannot convert 'nil' to type 'Image'`. My simplified code is below could anyone suggest a simple solution for this?

```
type Company struct {
    Name            string             `json:"name" bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Image           Image              `json:"image" bson:"image,omitempty"`
}

type Image struct {
    ID   string `json:"id" bson:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string `json:"name" bson:"name,omitempty"`
}

func checkCompanyCredibility(companies []Company) int{
    rating := 0
    for _, company := range companies{
        if company.Image != nil {
            rating =+ 3
            break
        }
    }
    return rating
}
```

Comment: The field `Image Image` cannot be `nil`, because struct types cannot be `nil`. You can test against empty, i.e. a zero-value instance of the struct, like so: `if company.Image != Image{} { ...`.

Comment: It's not a pointer, it cannot be `nil`, as the error says. What are you trying to accomplish? You don't need to check for `nil` here, it's guaranteed not to be `nil` due to type safety.

Comment: Use `*Image  ` type as Image in Company struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just to replace:

```
Image Image `json:"image" bson:"image,omitempty"`
```

To:

```
Image *Image `json:"image" bson:"image,omitempty"`
```

In this case `company.Image` will be pointer and you can check whether it's `nil`.